# Laravel Google OAuth Gender etc

Tags: laravel, google-authentication, laravel-socialite

I'm currently trying to integrate Google Authentication into my Laravel Application. I nearly managed to get everything working but still struggle with one aspect. I'm trying to fetch the gender, birthday and phone number, and the user also gets asked for the correct permissions, but I'm not receiving the fields after the callback comes back successful [image: Google Permissions(Unfortunately it's in german)]

Down below you can see the code with which I'm trying to fetch the right scopes. It's working perfectly fine for Facebook but for Google, as said, I'm still not receiving the fields. Does anyone know how to get it working? I found many tutorials but they never used scopes and sometimes also the old Google-API which makes it quite hard for me to figure it out myself.
Thank you very much in advance! :)

```
 case 'facebook':
                return Socialite::driver($provider)
                    // facebook
                    ->fields([
                        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday', 'location'
                    ])->scopes([
                        'email', 'user_birthday', 'user_gender, user_location'
                    ])->redirect();
            case 'google':
                return Socialite::driver($provider)
                    ->scopes([
                        'openid',
                        'profile',
                        'email',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read',
                        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read',

                    ])
                    ->stateless()
                    ->redirect();
```